# Objetos com For/In

Tags: javascript

> Eu tenho uma função adicionada em um protótipo, e não quero que ela
>   seja listada em um loop for/in e sim executá-da, mas ao chamar no
>   console, no loop for/in ela é exibida e não executada, então eu criei
>   um "if" de caso a leitura de dados do objeto seja uma função ele
>   executará a função (deu certo). Mas como eu posso ocultar a leitura da
>   função no console? eu quero que no momento que ela seja lida, ela a
>   execute, como posso fazer isso com um loop for/in?

Ao invés de exibir no console o trecho "function(){ console.log('vrum vrum');  }" - eu queria oculta-lo e exibir o que foi definido na função - o "vrum vrum".. a pergunta ficou confusa.. foi mau !?

```js
function CarroAspects(modelo, chassi, qtdPortas){
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.chassi = chassi;
    this.qtdPortas = qtdPortas;
}
CarroAspects.prototype.andar = function(){
    console.log('vrum vrum');
}
const carroPrototipo = new CarroAspects('protótipo', '1290381209', 2);
for(var carroProperty in carroPrototipo){
    console.log(carroPrototipo[carroProperty]); // console -> listará Propriedades do Objeto
    if(typeof carroPrototipo[carroProperty] === 'function'){ // Executará a função
        carroPrototipo[carroProperty]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar `Object.defineProperty()`  com  `enumerable: false,`, e isso vai esconder a propriedade de iteradores.

```js
function CarroAspects(modelo, chassi, qtdPortas) {
  this.modelo = modelo;
  this.chassi = chassi;
  this.qtdPortas = qtdPortas;
}
Object.defineProperty(CarroAspects.prototype, 'andar', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function() {
    console.log('vrum vrum');
  }
});
const carroPrototipo = new CarroAspects('protótipo', '1290381209', 2);
for (var carroProperty in carroPrototipo) {
  console.log(typeof carroPrototipo[carroProperty]); // var dar: string, string, number Objeto
}

console.log('Vamos dar uma volta?');
carroPrototipo.andar(); // vai dar : vrum vrum
```

---

*Edit depois do edit na pergunta:*

Se percebi bem deves usar um `getter` para fazer o que queres. Mais uma vez usando a mesma técnica (`Object.defineProperty`), mas com uma variante:

```js
function CarroAspects(modelo, chassi, qtdPortas) {
  this.modelo = modelo;
  this.chassi = chassi;
  this.qtdPortas = qtdPortas;
}

function vrumVrum() {
  return 'vrum vrum';
}
Object.defineProperty(CarroAspects.prototype, 'andar', {
  enumerable: true,
  get() {
    return vrumVrum();
  }
});
const carroPrototipo = new CarroAspects('protótipo', '1290381209', 2);
for (var carroProperty in carroPrototipo) {
  console.log(carroPrototipo[carroProperty]); // var dar: protótipo, 1290381209, 2, vrum vrum
}
```

Comment: Lembrando que o segundo argumento  do `Object.defineProperty()` pode ser um objeto com todos atributos e métodos que deseja adicionar, Ex:

    `Object.defineProperties(CarroAspects.prototype, {
      andar: {value: function() { console.log('vrum vrum');},enumerable: false},
      buzinar: {value: function() {console.log("beep beep");},enumerable: false}
    });`

Comment: Eu não quero ocultar os valores, eu quero que ao invés de exibir -- function(){  console.log('vrum vrum'); }, exiba "vrum vrum" ! a pergunta ficou meio confusa ..

Comment: É exatamente o que o @Sergio respondeu, para suprimir a "print" do prototype que está criando, você precisa implementá-lo como foi indicado e invocar o método ao final...

Comment: @BrunoB.Coelho juntei mais uma variante à resposta. Não estou a ver como queres usar isso, por isso pode ficar confuso perceber a resposta. Diz se faz sentido.

Comment: o primeiro código ta certo.. deu o resultado esperado.. !